# how to reference a text in align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I am trying to name an `align` environment and reference the entire formulation. For instance, let's see the the following example.

```
\begin{align} 
\text{My Model:}  \label{model}\nonumber   \\
\label{objective}
~\max   &~ \sum  x_i \\
\label{eq1}
s.t. &~ x_i \leq 1, & \forall i\in I \\
\end{align}
```

In the text file, I'd like to reference My Model, but it does not work. I have tried `\ref{model}` and `\nameref{model}` so far. Could someone help me?

Comment: You have `\nonumber` which suppresses the number in that line. What precisely do you want to achieve? Do you get what you want by either removing `\nonumber`, or by moving `\label{model}` after `\\ ` in this `align` environment?

Comment: I use ```\nonumber```, because I do not want to number the first line which represents the name of the model. I would like to reference the entire align environment. In the PDF file, when I reference it, it should show the name of the model which is ```My Model``` and when I click it, it should lead me to the formulation.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
\text{\hypertarget{model}{My Model}:}  \nonumber   \\
\label{objective}
~\max   &~ \sum  x_i \\
\label{eq1}
\text{s.t.} &~ x_i \leq 1, & \forall i\in I 
\end{align}
\clearpage
As evident from \hyperlink{model}{my model}, \dots
\end{document}`?

Comment: Thanks man, it works!  I do not know, if my question is duplicate or not but if you can share this an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I do not know if it is a duplicate, or more precisely, it depends on the definition of "duplicate" whether or not this is one. If you feel it is worthwhile to have an answer here, I will be happy to write one, it is your call.

Comment: Go ahead. Eventually you solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What one can always do is to work with `\hypertarget`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
\text{\hypertarget{model}{My Model}:}  \nonumber   \\
\label{objective}
~\max   &~ \sum  x_i \\
\label{eq1}
\text{s.t.} &~ x_i \leq 1, & \forall i\in I 
\end{align}
\clearpage
As evident from \hyperlink{model}{my model}, \dots
\end{document}
```